# Can I use changing variables in Excel formulas

Tags: excel

I have several worksheets with data that changes each month in new rows. After entering all of the data, I run various analyses that pull specific data from the worksheets. For example, one such analysis looks like:

```
=MeterReadings!K27-MeterReadings!K26
```

The columns ("K") do not change, but the rows increase by one each month.

Is there a way that I can simply specify a new row number-- e.g. "x" and "y" -- and have all of the analysis formula automatically regenerate.

```
Current month:   x= 27
Prior month:     y= 26
```

Then

```
=MeterReadings!K"x"-MeterReadings!K"y"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `INDIRECT` function. It allows you to create a cell reference from a regular string of letters and numbers. Your example might go something like:

`=INDIRECT("MeterReadings!K" & CountA(K:K)) - INDIRECT("MeterReadings!K" & CountA(K:K)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that the cell a1 is for the value x and cell b1 is for value y,
On c1 enter:

```
=INDIRECT("MeterReadings!K"&B1)-INDIRECT("MeterReadings!K"&B2)
```

Comment: This was very helpful!